# gdrive -bash: /usr/bin/drive: cannot execute binary file

Tags: shell, software-installation

I am processing hundreds of image files on a weekly basis and `gdrive` would be perfect for automatically making duplicate copies of the raw images for archive before the originals go through the processing pipeline. But I cannot get it to work.

The machine I am working on has the Mavericks operating system. I have tried compiling the binary with go as well as using the command

```
 cd && sudo install drive-darwin-amd64 /usr/local/bin/drive
```

Both processes do not come up with errors but when I type in drive into the shell I get:

> -bash: /usr/bin/drive: cannot execute binary file

Are there any other options for installing gdrive?

Comment: Since you're asking about installing the sync client rather than the Web interface, your question would be better at [su] or [unix.se].

Comment: what are the results of the following commands: `id -a` and `ls -ld /usr/bin/drive`?

Comment: You mention installing to `/usr/local/bin/drive` but then trying to run `/usr/bin/drive`. Something's wrong here.

Comment: Thanh-Lan Did you solve this problem? How